# Changing Pandas .loc output format

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very quick/simple question. I have created a list from a data table, and used .loc to extract values from my data table into my list. However, I want to change the format into something else.

Here is my current code:

```
import re
import os
import pandas as pd

os.chdir('C:/Users/Sams PC/Desktop')
f=open('test5.txt', 'w')

test1=pd.read_csv('test1.txt', sep='\s+', header=None)
test1.columns=['Column_1','Column_2','Column_3']
test2=pd.read_csv('test2.txt', sep='\s+', header=None)
test2.columns=['Column_1','Column_2','Column_3','Column_4']
x=re.findall('[A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z]-[H][N]',str(test1))
y=re.findall('[A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z]-[C][A]-[H][N]',str(test2))
data=[]
for i in range (0,2):
    if x[i] in str(test1):
        data2=test1.set_index('Column_1',drop=False)
        data3=(data2.loc[str(x[i]), 'Column_2':'Column_3'])
        print(data3)
        data.append(data3)
        if y[i] in str(test2):
            data2=test2.set_index('Column_1',drop=False)
            data3=(data2.loc[str(y[i]),'Column_3'])
            data.append(data3)
        else:
            print('Not Found')
    else:
        print('Not Found')

print (data)
f.write(str(data))
f.close()
```

My output:

```
[Column_2    114.424
Column_3       7.39
Name: S31N-HN, dtype: object, 61.717, Column_2    121.981
Column_3      7.468
Name: Y32N-HN, dtype: object, 60.788999999999994]
```

While the script is doing exactly what I want it to do (getting the proper values from S31N and Y32N from my data tables), the format right now is unusable. Ideally I'd like a nice simple list such as:

```
114.424
7.39
61.717
121.981
7.468
60.78
```

Or if possible, it'd be nice to have the index values used next to them as well. I.E.

```
S31N-HN 114.424
S31N-HN 7.39
S31N-CA-HN 61.717
etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
data.append(list(data3.values))
```

Update 
`data.append(list(data3))` works only when it is a Series i.e you are selecting a single row

Comment: That gives the error:  data.append(list(data3))
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable

You get the same error even if you add data3.values

Well its more at every iteration I am creating a single column (or at least that's the idea of .loc). I'm creating a column of the values from column2 and column 3.

Comment: you need to remove list when you are doing `data3=(data2.loc[str(y[i]),'Column_3'])` because it is selecting a single value here. so, in this case you can do `data.append(data3)`

Comment: I'm already doing data.append(data3). That's what is giving me the output I'm trying to reformat/change.

Comment: In first case where you are selecting 2 columns i.e ` data3=(data2.loc[str(x[i]), 'Column_2':'Column_3'])` you do `data.extend(list(data3))` and in the second case where you are selecting single value i.e. `data3=(data2.loc[str(y[i]),'Column_3'])` you do `data.append(data3)`.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick, thank you!! Is there anyways to get this list vertical instead of horizontal (e.g. transposing an array)? Basically write the output of x in zip(data) (I can get it to print the way I want, but I don't know how to write the file that way)